# How to send a touch input to stage in Libgdx?

Tags: java, libgdx

I am trying to map a keyboard's key to touch a certain point on stage.
This is my current code but it doesn't crash or do anything.

```
InputEvent touch = new InputEvent();
touch.setType(InputEvent.Type.touchUp);
touch.setStageX(400);
touch.setStageY(200);
currentStage.getRoot().fire(touch); //this doesn't do anything
```

currentStage instance is created and set as InputProcessor. I have place a button on 400,200 to capture the event but the code above failed to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are expecting the InputEvent to cause each actor in the heirarchy to be compared to the coordinates to determine if it responds. That's not how Stage handles input events.

When actual screen touches occur, Stage determines which actor was touched and fires the InputEvent directly on that actor. If you fire a manually-created InputEvent on the root, only the root has an opportunity to respond to it.

If you want to manually create an input event and let the stage figure out which actor to give it to, you can call `stage.hit()` and if it returns an Actor, that's the touchable Actor that was under the touched point, and you can fire the event on that Actor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use next methods of `Stage` for emulation of user engagement:

```
/** 
 * Applies a touch down event to the stage and returns true if an actor 
 * in the scene {@link Event#handle() handled} the event. 
 */
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button)

/** 
 * Applies a touch moved event to the stage and returns true if an actor
 * in the scene {@link Event#handle() handled} the
 * event. Only {@link InputListener listeners} that returned true for 
 * touchDown will receive this event. 
 */
public boolean touchDragged (int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) 

/** 
 * Applies a touch up event to the stage and returns true if an actor 
 * in the scene {@link Event#handle() handled} the event.
 * Only {@link InputListener listeners} that returned true for 
 * touchDown will receive this event. 
 */
public boolean touchUp (int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button)
```

In your case:

```
 Vector2 point = new Vector2(400, 300);
 currentStage.stageToScreenCoordinates(point);
 // this method works with screen coordinates
 currentStage.touchDown((int)point.x, (int)point.y, 0, 0);
```